# How to judge whether selected result is empty or not with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, resultset

```
$("#experiences tr")
```

For the above  one,how to judge if it's empty or not?

I thought its boolean value should be false,but seems not.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

use the length property:

```
$("#experiences tr").length
```

if it's 0 it's empty

Answer (score 1):

```
var experienceRows = $('#experiences tr'),
    len = experienceRows.length;

if ( len ) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: To reduce another lookup to the same group of elements in later code by creating a variable if lots of manipulation code is done on `experienceRows`. `len` is not really required. Does this really deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you just want to affect only the empty elements, use

```
$('#experiences tr:empty')
```

or the other way around:

```
$('#experiences tr:not(:empty)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#experiences tr:empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//More Improved and Accurate - Trim white spaces as well

//Define

function trim(str) {
    return( ("" + str).replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/[\s]+/g,' ').replace(/\s+$/,'') ); 
}

//Call

if(trim(frmObj.element.value).length ==0) { //true }
```